# Scene Graph with VTK

Tags: vtk, openinventor, coin3d

It seems like there isn't anything about creating a scene graph with VTK. I have to replace Coin3d (and SoQt) with VTK in a software. Since Coin3d is focusing on scene graphs i don't know how i could replace some classes provided by Coin3d (for example [SoSeparator](https://grey.colorado.edu/coin3d/classSoSeparator.html)).

I also can't find any tutorials/introductions to creating scene graphs with VTK. Anyone knows some resource for that? Or is using VTK to create scene graphs a bad idea?

Comment: May be you came across this already but VTK seems to have a Scene Graph rendering module. All the relevant header files are listed [here](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/dir_ee71efe70e839f28b98a7b63095a5a8d.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes i've seen it but there's sadly 0 documentation and i found only like 5 questions about scene graphs with vtk. All of them were unanswered and like 15 years ago...

Comment: I was on the brink of replacing Coin3D and SoQt but the maintainers have dome a lot of really great work in the last few months and these now work like a charm.  They build clean with cmake on windows and *nix.

Comment: @emsr The software which still uses Coin3D and SoQt can't render anything. The graphics are there because i can click on them, but they're "invisible" and the console is showing an error and telling me that rendering will be flawed. I can tell you the exact error later but did you face something similar?

Comment: @Awastaken I couldn't even build the software on either Linux or Windows.  This is solved now.  In your case I wonder if you're missing a light or a camera.  I've had warnings of my OpenGL environment not supporting some feature but nothing that stopped me from seeing or interacting.